# What is this waveform?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, closed-form

Consider the following infinite series:

$\text{f} \left( x \right) =\displaystyle \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\sin \left( n x\right)}{n^2}$

We know that $\text{f} \left( x \right)$ is convergent by the squeeze theorem.  The graph of $\text{f} \left( x \right)$ is shown below:

[image: ???]

Is there a way to express this periodic function in a closed-form expression, rather than a sum?

Specifically, I am wondering if there is a way to represent $\text{f} \left( x \right)$ in the form of something like $k\cdot \text{g} \left( \sin \left( x \right) \right)$, or $k \cdot \sin \left( \text{g} \left( x \right) \right)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the famous [*Clausen function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Comment: Interesting!  When I ask questions like these, I rarely expect the closed form expression to have a formal name.  And it even has a nice generalization for different powers in the denominator terms.